# Google IOT - What is the max limit of Device telemetry publishes per project

Tags: google-cloud-iot

As per Google IOT docs, Rate limits of **"Device telemetry publishes per project"** is "Unlimited, but the default is 60,000 per min" and can be increased. Is there a max limit to which this can be increased? 
Similarly what is the max limit for **"Device manager API modifyCloudToDeviceConfig calls per project"** and **"Open MQTT connections, active HTTP device connections (within the past 5 minutes), or both, per project per region"**

The other confusion is "Device MQTT connections and HTTP requests per project" is limited to 60000 per minute and this cannot be increased. However "Open MQTT connections, active HTTP device connections (within the past 5 minutes), or both, per project per region" is limited to 10000 and can be increased. Does this mean that in a 1-minute span, a max of 60000 connection requests can be made but there is no limit to the total no of MQTT connections alive?

Answer (score 2):

For practical purposes, as you can see, almost all of the knobs can be increased upon request. The big reason they're there is to ensure we don't have idle resources lying around. If you are beyond these limits, it sounds like you've got a significant project and we'd love to discuss your requirements and expand the limits as you need.

So, the HTTP connection request limit is actually for auth requests, which functionally is the same, but just a confusion on the docs. That IS currently limited for HTTP but not MQTT as an assumption was made that MQTT would be the high throughput option because of the overwhelming benefits of MQTT for larger throughput, but if you have a project that has a requirement of using HTTP for high throughput, we definitely want to hear about it. I've talked to the eng team, and it's not something we can't change, but it is involved so we'd like to hear more about what the HTTP high connection requirement entails.

Comment: thank you for taking time to reply. We do have a significant project which requires at least 2 million MQTT connections at any given time. Is this achievable with Google IOT? We don't need HTTP connections, just MQTT is sufficient. Can we request for increasing the limits to 2 million connections and accordingly increase the no of publishes to similar no?

Comment: Potentially yes, but let's talk offline. Your project is one that should be brought up the food chain here for sure. Drop me an email at gweiss at google dot com and I'll loop in some folks to chat about the project and be sure you can do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. I have sent an email. Please check